# Declare a function as global

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use my own logger as a replacement for console.log(). My problem is that I have to import my logger function in all files where I use it.

I would like to declare my custom logger function as global to access it in other files without import/requirements.

The global object is limited to the file where we declare the property. Does anyone know a way to make my custom logger globally accessible?

Thanks to all of you.

Comment: You can set it as part of the global, but just write a macro in your IDE that inserts it into your new files.

Comment: @epascarello
How can I do it on Visual Studio Code please ?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: "*The global object is limited to the file where we declare the property.*" - uh, no?

Comment: "*I have to import my logger function in all files where I use it.*" - that is not a problem, rather it is a best practice.

Comment: @Bergi I have to agree, but some things are different for people working on their personal projects instead of working for larger, team based ones. Convenience is pretty nice to have too :D